# Windows Forms Windows 8 Theme

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2012

How to apply windows 8 theme for windows forms ?

[image]

Note : What i want to achieve is clearly using the style so that any user [with\without] windows 8 installed can see my application with windows 8 style. {Just Like Any Other Style?]

Comment: They're automatically themed as such if you have Windows 8 installed.

Comment: No i want to use it so it is built in the app just like any other styles. So non windows 8 users can see my application with windows 8 window style

Comment: Please don't do that. Themes provide user feedback for things like window behavior, snapping, drag-and-drop, tiling, et al. and by using a different OS's theme you are misleading users. Themes exist to support things like people with disabilities and automation, and by overriding that you are defeating its purpose.

Comment: There is a lot of applications with custom styles but i like the one of windows 8 because it is some how elegant...

Comment: Yeah, for instance Visual Studio applies it's own theme, and I love it for it. I want to do the same with some of my Windows forms applications, at least give users the option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you would want to, because it makes your UI inconsistent with other applications in the OS - chances are users won't be happy. To help you convert the whole OS, there are 3rd party themes available on the internet. For Windows 7, there is [one by deviantart](http://mare-m.deviantart.com/art/Windows-8-RTM-Theme-for-Windows-7-318932206). Or try [Windows 8 Transformation pack](http://www.thememypc.com/windows-8-transformation-pack-6-0/), which supposedly can even work on XP.

If you want to style your particular app, there are 3rd party UI components you can use, but they are all paid (from what I know). Some vendors, for example, are [Devexpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Subscriptions/DXperience/DXv2/index.xml?page=47) and [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-8/overview.aspx).

Comment: lol i don't want a transformation pack i only want to use the style in my application on. just as any styled wpf application but in windows forms

Comment: i already have Devexpress and it has amazing features and styles yet no windows 8 style

Comment: @RuneS: check skin name = Metropolis. It looks like [this](http://www.devexpress.com/Subscriptions/DXperience/DXv2/index.xml?page=47), which is very much metro-ish.

Comment: wow this is awesome idk how i forgot to check the XtraFrom.. Thank you very much.